# Set text state to active on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/RKZ8s/

I want it so when the page loads the 'instagram' text is already colored in, then can switch between the others. Couldn't find how to set it to 'active' onLoad or some how.

```
$(".filter").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
);

$(".filter").click(function() {
    $(".filter").removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Why not just give it the `active` class in your HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/RKZ8s/1/

Comment: Sorry, still kind of a noob, didn't know it was that easy. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Class active in Html

```
<div class="button one" ><a href="#" class="filter active">instagram</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it adds the class active when the page finishes loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".filter:first").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: to all elements, just first one needs class active.